# Dart PowerSNMP GetTable does not return any record

Tags: snmp, dart-communications

I am using dart powerSNMP for .Net.
I am trying to query a table using GetTable(), it does not work for me.

Below C# code does not return any row,

```
        const string address = "xxx.xxx.xx.x";
        using (var mgr = new Manager())
        {
            var slave = new ManagerSlave(mgr);
            slave.Socket.ReceiveTimeout = 13000;
            try
            {
                //Retrieve table using GetNext requests
                Variable[,] table = slave.GetTable("1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.1.1.9",
                                                    SnmpVersion.Three,
                                                    null,
                                                    new Security()
                                                        {
                                                            AuthenticationPassword = "mypassword1",
                                                            AuthenticationProtocol = AuthenticationProtocol.Md5,
                                                            PrivacyPassword = "mypassword2",
                                                            PrivacyProtocol = PrivacyProtocol.Des
                                                        },
                                                    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), 161),
                                                    0);


            }catch(Exception ez)
            {

            }
        }
```

This is supposed to return a set of records from given OID. but It does not return me anything. When I use MIB Browser, I see GetBulk operation fetches all the records for me.

But what is wrong with GetTable() here?

Comment: The tag net-snmp is for something else, so don't misuse it. As I don't think Dart support monitors StackOverflow discussions (the tag was created by me), you should try to contact its support directly, http://dart.com/support.aspx

Comment: @LexLi thanks for adding a new tag. I don't have sufficient permission to add a tag that's why ended up using a closely matching tag.